# How do I use re.sub to replace a specific iteration?

Tags: python-3.7

I'm making a madlibs python program for a project, and I'm having trouble replacing the specific words in my input.

I want to change the individual iterations, not all of them.
Go easy on me, I'm a newb

```py
# Run a loop to replace the words

print("Replacing Words...")

for loopCount in range(replacedNumber):
    currentReplace = replaceList[loopCount] 
    print(re.finditer(r'<.*?>',storyContent))
    print("Replacing", currentReplace)
    filteredReplaced = re.sub(r'<.*?>',currentReplace, storyContent, loopCount)
```

Note: The print() lines where just for debugging

[Here is a link to all of the code](https://github.com/CCF100/python-project/blob/0f830805ea4b75e22d6834d926ef893c599573fb/madlibs.py)

[Console Output](https://pastebin.com/jm1urAb2)

Comment: Awesome that you posted a concise question, but you may not get a lot of help because your code sample isn't usable as is and it is not clear exactly what error or unexpected output you are getting. Rather than posting a snippet of your code with a link to the rest (which many people won't look at), check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I added a pastebin to the console output.